# Update Product using API IN Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, product

I am trying to update woocommerce product from api i have with me, along with wp import plugin to sync product, variant products are not appearing in same.

Link to products csv, as api is same https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H_stJpIQEUGZtZZZ0DzApN-a0PdUD6VxAWJLmVluzXY/edit#gid=0